# Codeigniter query to mssql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, codeigniter

How do i convert this line of code into a query which will be accepted by MSSQL Server 2012?

Im getting this error **Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\pis\application\models\main.php** That happens when im trying to convert it into a query for mssql

```
      function login($username, $password) {



        $this -> db -> select();
        $this -> db -> from('tbl_user');
        $this -> db -> JOIN('tbl_assign_role', 'tbl_user.u_id = tbl_assign_role.tar_owner_id');
        $this -> db -> where('tbl_user.u_uname = ' . "'" . htmlspecialchars($username) . "'"); 
        $this -> db -> where('tbl_user.u_pword = ' . "'" . MD5($password) . "'"); 
        $this -> db -> where('tbl_user.is_active = 1'); 
        $this -> db -> limit(1);
        $query = $this -> db -> get();

        if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
        {
            return $query->result();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

I change it into this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user
                  LEFT JOIN tbl_assign_role ON tbl_user.u_id = tbl_assign_role.tar_owner_id
                  WHERE tbl_user.u_name = '".$username."'
                  AND tbl_user.u_pword = '".MD5($password)."'
                  AND tbl_user.is_active = 1
                  FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
                  ";
```

After i changed, that became the error.

It's working now. What I've done is

```
$query = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tbl_user 
        JOIN tbl_assign_role ON tbl_user.u_id = tbl_assign_role.tar_owner_id 
        WHERE tbl_user.u_uname = '".htmlspecialchars($username)."' 
        AND tbl_user.u_pword = '".MD5($password)."' 
        AND tbl_user.is_active = 1";

        $query = $this->db->query($query);
```

Comment: I don't know codeigniter at all. But doesn't `num_rows` method require any arguments?

Comment: In codeigniter it doesnt need an argument.

Comment: you want to convert this query in MySql from codeigniter method right ?

Comment: there is an function in codeigniter that will convert whole codeigniter query to a sql command. please use $this->db->last_query(); it will give you sql statement and then you can use it as you wish.

Comment: after using $query->result(); can I use return $this->db->last_query(); ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi hope this will help you...

```
"SELECT tbl_user.*,tbl_assign_role.* FROM tbl_user left join tbl_assign_role on tbl_assign_role.tar_owner_id = tbl_user.u_id where tbl_user.u_uname = '".htmlspecialchars($username)."' and tbl_user.u_pword ='".MD5($password)."' and tbl_user.is_active='1' limit 1";
```